# PhantomJS file upload not working with XPath expression

Tags: javascript, file-upload, phantomjs, casperjs

I can't seem to be able to make [fileUpload](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html) work, I am using the script below but from the screenshot it is obvious that the file is not even selected in the form: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSiCA.png)

```
  casper.thenOpen('https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/', function () {

    this.waitForSelector(x('//input[@type="file"]'), function () {
      casper.page.uploadFile(x('//input[@type="file"]'), '/Users/stratos/Desktop/IMG_1344.png');
    });
  });
  casper.then(function () {
    this.wait(5000, function () {
       this.capture('test/integration/screenshots/uploadTest.png');
    });
  });
```

The test runs fine with no errors so I have no indication what is going on :(

I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1 and CasperJS 1.1.0-beta5

If the test presses the Upload button the page validation will trigger because of no file selected.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase it properly, the problem is that the file is not being selected in the first place, pressing the Begin Upload button will just cause the page validation to trigger because of No file selected. I am afraid I can't upload the screenshot with the result because of my low reputation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`page.uploadFile()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html) is a PhantomJS function and doesn't support CasperJS' use of XPath expressions. It only accepts CSS selectors as a simple string:

```
casper.page.uploadFile('input[type="file"]', '/Users/stratos/Desktop/IMG_1344.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
casper.then(function () {
    var fileName = "/file path/";
    this.evaluate(function (fileName) {
        __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').setAttribute('value', fileName)
    }, {fileName: fileName});
    this.page.uploadFile('input[type="file"]', fileName);
    console.log('Selecting file');
});
casper.then(function () {
    console.log("Clicking on Upload to notebook check box");
    this.click(x("Xpath of uploading button"));
    console.log("Clicking on Submit icon");
});
```